# Trigger for the nexval in a sequence returing ORA-01403

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a page in Apex where the user can connect a row from a table to another (a mail to the address) because we changed how we store addresses so we are connecting the two tables while working on them.

The link between the tables is a row in a third table that has 5 columns (ID||ID_RACC||ID_INDIRIZZO||DATA_INS||USER_INS), where ID is the main ID of the link-table, ID_RACC is the ID of the mail's table and ID_INDIRIZZO is the ID of the addresses' table.

If I try from the shell to run this query:

```
INSERT INTO INSERT INTO INDIRIZZI_RACCOMANDATE (ID_RACC, ID_INDIRIZZO, USER_INS, DATA_INS)
VALUES (p_id_racc, p_id_indirizzo, v('USER'), SYSDATE);
```

with p_id_racc, p_id_indirizzo non-empty variables, I don't have any problem.

But if the user select from a Select List the address and click the Save button from a specific page he/she receives

```
ORA-01403: no data found
```

the only code that is run from him/her is the above one.

I searched and I found out that the problem could be the trigger that fills the ID column in the table INDIRIZZI_RACCOMANDATE from a sequence.

The trigger code is:

```
create or replace trigger "BI_INDIRIZZI_RACCOMANDATE"
BEFORE
insert on "INDIRIZZI_RACCOMANDATE"
for each row
begin
if :NEW."ID" is null then 
  select "INDIRIZZI_RACCOMANDATE_SEQ".nextval into :NEW."ID" from sys.dual; 
end if; 
end;​
```

I can't understand how is it possible to have a *no_data_found* with only a select nextval from a sequence.
Then I can't understand how is it possible that I have this problem only if I run it from that page and don't have it if I run the exact same code from shell.

Comment: Perhaps `v('USER)` is causing the error.

Comment: I would also have a suggest reading through this https://svenweller.wordpress.com/2016/02/24/sequence-and-audit-columns-with-apex-5-and-12c/

Answer (score 0):

> But if the user select from a Select List the address and click the Save button from a specific page he/she receives `ORA-01403: no data found`

While in Apex, use `:APP_USER`:

```
INSERT INTO INSERT INTO INDIRIZZI_RACCOMANDATE 
  (ID_RACC, ID_INDIRIZZO, USER_INS, DATA_INS)
VALUES 
  (p_id_racc, p_id_indirizzo, :APP_USER, SYSDATE);
                              ^^^^^^^^^
                              this
```

---

By the way, `v('USER')` is suspicious; should have been `v('APP_USER')`, I presume.

Comment: I tried both with `v('APP_USER')` and `:APP_USER` and they gave me back `ORA-01403: no data found`

Comment: i don't have Apex installed, but search the Manual. It will list every available option.

Comment: @Belayer and saying more, if I pass a constant like 'NAME' it gives me back `no data found` anyway, so in my opinion, it's not the `:APP_USER` the problem

Comment: Did you try to a) run the page in debug mode and see whether it reveals some additional information; b) create a table into which you'll store values used in your code. How? By an automomous transaction procedure (so that you could COMMIT in it and not affect other transactions which will let you examine table's contents and see which value is, actually, missing. It seems we're just blind guessing here ...

Comment: @Littlefoot I'm literally blind guessing because I've no idea about what's missing. a) I've already tried and i got no more information than a  `ORA-01403: no data found`. b) I think I don't get what you are saying, I have 4 variables that I'm trying to insert into a table and: `p_id_racc` and `p_id_indirizzo` are not null for sure, `:APP_USER` or whatever you want is not null (I tried also to use a static value and It didn't work) and `SYSDATE` that is not null.

Comment: @Littlefoot I'm sure about the trigger that fills the ID column in the table because I tried to create a table without any trigger and the insert query works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

V (an absolutely abhorrent  object name Oracle should know better) is defined as a **collection indexed by varchar2**. Your problem is that 'USER' is not a valid index value for V. When a collection does not contain the referenced index value on a collection Oracle throws *NO DATA FOUND*. A bad choice but the one they made. That is how you get that error. use v('APP_USER');  See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=69955ad4855987b10ef9be5f253d02a6) and below.

```
declare 
   type example_att 
        is table of varchar2(30)   
        index by varchar2(8);
   example_data example_att;    
begin 
   dbms_output.enable;
   example_data('A') := 'Abcd';
   example_data('E') := 'Efgh';
   example_data('I') := 'Ijlk';
 
   dbms_output.put_line( 'value for ''A'' is ' );
   dbms_output.put_line( example_data('A') );
   -- OOPS
   dbms_output.put_line( 'value for ''L'' is ' );
   dbms_output.put_line( example_data('L'));
end;
/
```

Comment: I tried both with `v('APP_USER')` and `:APP_USER` and they gave me back `ORA-01403: no data found`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message for a procedure I would call in a dynamic action. The Procedure takes two arguments where one is the APP_USER.

```
BOOKMARK_FAVORITE(v('CARD_ID'), v('APP_USER'));
```

In my Procedure I would then select the User_ID for this specific APP_USER. And here is where the error was. The username I was selecting was not in Uppercase but the APP_USER was (IN_USERNAME). So I had to use the UPPER function:

```
select au.user_id into IN_USER_ID
from app_user au
where UPPER(au.username) = IN_USERNAME; --IN_USERNAME = APP_USER
      ^^^^^
```

Apparantly once the user log's in, the username will be stored in APP_USER in UPPERCASE, irrespective of how user has entered in log-in screen.

Don't know if this will help in your situation though :/